# Conditional expectation of random products of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose that $X_i, i \in \mathbb{N}$ are integrable, independent random variables and $N:\Omega \to \mathbb{N}$ a random variable independent from all $X_i$. Does it hold that
$\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^{N}X_i|N]=\prod_{i=1}^{N}\mathbb{E}[X_i|N]$?

I tried doing it by definition, but I get stuck at one point. After that, I tried to define $f(N, X_1, X_2, ...):=\prod_{i=1}^{N}X_i$, which is a measurable function, and then I tried to write $$\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^{N}X_i|N](\omega)=\mathbb{E}[f(N, X_1, X_2, ...)|N](\omega)=\mathbb{E}[f(N(\omega),X_1, X_2,...)]=\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^{N(\omega)}X_i]\overset{indep.}{=}\\=\prod_{i=1}^{N(\omega)}\mathbb{E}[X_i]\overset{indep.}{=}\prod_{i=1}^{N(\omega)}\mathbb{E}[X_i|N]$$
where the second equality is a naive generalization of $\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)|\mathcal{F}](\omega)=\mathbb{E}[f(X(\omega),Y)]$ when $X$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}$ and $Y$ is independent from it, which is a well-known property of conditional expectations.

So, my questions are does the original statement hold and is this naive generalization correct?

Comment: The statement is true, and your calculation seems pretty much correct. Though I’m not sure why one bothers with the conditions on $N$ in the problem statement since the $X_i$ are independent of it and it drops out.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen The $X_i$ are independent of $N$ and then $\prod_{i=1}^nX_i$ is independent of $N$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$, but $\prod_{i=1}^NX_i$ most likely will depend (probabilistically) on $N$, since it depends functionally.

Comment: The conditional expectation w.r.t. the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal N$ generated by) $N$ is a step function with (countably many) steps of the shape $\{N=n\}$, where $n$ runs in $\mathbb N$. Then we have only to know  the averages of the corresponding random variables on  atoms of $\mathcal N$. And $\displaystyle\mathbb E\left[\prod_{1\le k\le N}X_k|N=n\right]$ is related to $\displaystyle\mathbb E\left[\prod_{1\le k\le N}X_k\cdot 1_{\{N=n\}}\right]=\mathbb E\left[\prod_{1\le k\le n}X_k\cdot 1_{\{N=n\}}\right]=\mathbb E\left[\prod_{1\le k\le n}X_k\right]\cdot \mathbb E\left[1_{\{N=n\}}\right]$.

Comment: @Alejandro I certainly agree that the answer is a random variable that is a function of $N$. I just would have wrote it $\prod^N E(X_i)$ rather than $\prod^N E(X_i\mid N)$

Comment: I don't believe the original statement is true.  The left side is a definite number, while the right side is a random variable, with a distribution depending on the distribution of N.

Comment: In the original statement there are a conditional expectation (a random variable) and the product of a random number of conditional expectations (a product of a random quantity of random variables, wich is also a random variable). I see no constant number there.